# how to configure route53 to nearest s3 endpoint

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

If I have 3 different s3 buckets all in different regions, how can I configure route53 to route requests to the nearest endpoints?

I have added the 4 DNS records for a sub domain in my domain registrar.

Answer (score 1):

Route53 has latency based routing, but I think you can do this only for EC2 and ELB and not S3.

Documentation is telling it this way:

Creating Latency Resource Record Sets - Amazon Route 53 : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingLatencyRRSets.html

**Another important point**: Typically you serve large objects (in MBs) from S3. If you need to make it available fast across different Geos, the best method would be to use CDN ( Cloudfront) with one S3 bucket with all the resources as the "origin server". More details @ [Using CloudFront with Amazon S3 - Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigrateS3ToCloudFront.html)

**For upload acceleration**: Cloudfront now supports [POST/PUT](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/) aswell. This can be used to accelerate your file uploads.

Comment: I thought there is option to choose s3 for the alias target?

Comment: You can, but I doubt if you can use "latency" routing on this. Anycase, since your objective is to reduce download latency, Cloud-front approach is specifically for this.

Comment: Ic. Actually I am looking to improve upload experience by choosing nearest endpoint.

Comment: Cloudfront recently supported this for needs like yours: Announcing Amazon CloudFront Support for POST, PUT and other HTTP Methods : http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/

Comment: Cool! But will there be multiple bucket endpoints which cloudfront will route the upload, or just a single endpoint and cloudfront route via the optimized path?

Comment: You can set it up either way, using the rules based on path or query param.

Comment: Thank you. You have been very helpful! To get this right, I suppose I can add 3 S3 endpoints as origins, each with the same file.txt. When user requests the file, CF will route the user to the nearest edge location. The edge location then get the file from the nearest origin (nearest between edge location and origub, not nearest between user and origin). For user upload, suppose there is no behavior, CF will use the nearest edge location to retrieve the user file, which will then distribute back to 3 origins? Is this the default behavior?